# ExtJS 4 form validation

Tags: validation, extjs4

I have simple form (5 textfields) and one of them I have to validate (check if it's value is unique in the list from store). So my code is the following:

```
    {
        xtype:      'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        itemId:     'BRW_NAME',
        vtype:      'alphanum',
        validator:  function (tab)  {
                       Ext.getStore('BrwStore').each(function(rec)  {
                           if (rec.get('brw_nazwa') == tab)  {
//debugger;
                              Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#BRW_NAME').markInvalid('DOUBLE NAME ERROR!');
                              return (false);
                           }
                       });
                       return (true);
    }
```

but after I enter the same value (the same as in the store) this field stay valid. When I use "debugger" I see that this field is marked as invalid (red frame around field and procedure return false) but I can see it only in this moment. When I loose debugger control the field become normal (I mean without red frame).

Why? 
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why but when this validation error is set outsite "each" loop, like this:

```
    {
            xtype:      'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            itemId:     'BRW_NAME',
            vtype:      'alphanum',
            validator:  function (tab)  {
                           var err = false;

                           Ext.getStore('BrwStore').each(function(rec)  {
                               if (rec.get('brw_nazwa') == tab)  err = true;
                           });
                           if (err)  {
                                Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#BRW_NAME').markInvalid();
                                return 'DOUBLE NAME ERROR!';
                           }
                           return (true);
        }
```

everything is ok.